# Comparing date values for two columns

Tags: date, sql-server-2012

I have a column called `PairDt`, a string that contains a date value in the last 5 characters. I want to compare that date value with the date value in the `Day` column, which contains dates in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```
PairDt                  Day
----------------------------------
DCS-CNY-Yunbi-42606     2016-08-24
DCS-CNY-Yunbi-42607     2016-08-25
DCS-CNY-Yunbi-42608     2016-08-26
DCS-CNY-Yunbi-42609     2016-08-27
DCS-CNY-Yunbi-42610     2016-08-28
```

How do I convert `Day` to a value?

I'm trying to isolate Date values in `PairDt` that does not match the date value in Days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This 5 digit number at the end of PairDt looks like number of days since December 30th 1899. To convert this number to date use DATEADD to add as many days. To convert a date to number, use DATEDIFF to calculate the number of days. Something like this code:

```
declare @PairDt varchar(50) = 'DCS-CNY-Yunbi-42606', @Day date = '2016-08-24'
select DATEADD(d, cast(right(@PairDt, 5) as int), '1899-12-30'), DATEDIFF(day, '1899-12-30', @Day)
```